# Locale conversion not working with product flavors

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-transitions, android-productflavors

My application has a feature of changing application langugae to English, Arabic or Russian.This application has different product flavors i.e Flavor1, Flavor2. Every flavor application will have this option to convert application language to English,Arabic,Russian.I have placed strings files in both flavors separately and have not placed any strings file in main. But when i change the language from option it just changes the direction supposed right to left for arabic but the strings doesn't get translated.

*Below is strings files hierarchy.*

```
     Flavor1 
      values
        strings.xml [Contains all english strings]
      values-ar
        strings.xml [Contains all arabic strings]
       values-ru
         strings.xml [Contains all russian strings]
     main 
      values
        Contains colors,dimens but no strings file
    Flavor2 
      values
        strings.xml [Contains all english strings]
      values-ar
        strings.xml [Contains all arabic strings]
       values-ru
         strings.xml [Contains all russian strings]
```

*Below is code of SettingsFragment where application language is changed.*

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("OnCreate:", "Preference Fragment");
        LanguageLocale.getInstance().getResources().updateConfiguration(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getConfiguration(), LanguageLocale.getInstance().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        LanguageLocale.getInstance().getResources().updateConfiguration(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getConfiguration(), LanguageLocale.getInstance().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Log.e("OnResume:", "Preference Fragment");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("OnDestroy:", "Preference Fragment");
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {

        Log.e("OnCreatePreference:", "Preference Fragment");
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_include);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
        Preference preference = findPreference(s);
        Log.e("PF", "In OnSharedPreferenceChanged");
        if (null != preference) {
            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                String selectedlang = null;
                Log.e("Key: ", preference.getKey());

                sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));
                LanguageLocale.getInstance().setContext(getContext());
                LanguageLocale.getInstance().setResources(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getResources());
                LanguageLocale.getInstance().setConfiguration(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getResources().getConfiguration());
                String value = sharedPreferences.getString(preference.getKey(), null);

                assert value != null;
                if (value.equals(getString(R.string.TEXT_LABEL_ENGLISH))) {
                    ((ListPreference) preference).setDefaultValue(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.TEXT_LABEL_ENGLISH));
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().setLocale(new Locale("en"));
                    Locale.setDefault(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getLocale());
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().setConfiguration(new Configuration());
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().getConfiguration().setLocale(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getLocale());
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().getContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getConfiguration(), LanguageLocale.getInstance().getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                } else if (value.equals(getString(R.string.TEXT_LABEL_RUSSIAN))) {
                    ((ListPreference) preference).setDefaultValue(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.TEXT_LABEL_RUSSIAN));
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().setLocale(new Locale("ru"));
                    Locale.setDefault(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getLocale());
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().setConfiguration(new Configuration());
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().getConfiguration().setLocale(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getLocale());
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().getContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getConfiguration(), LanguageLocale.getInstance().getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                }

                // Arabic Language setting added internalization
                else if (value.equals(getString(R.string.TEXT_LABEL_ARABIC))) {
                    ((ListPreference) preference).setDefaultValue(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.TEXT_LABEL_ARABIC));
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().setLocale(new Locale("ar"));
                    Locale.setDefault(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getLocale());
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().setConfiguration(new Configuration());
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().getConfiguration().setLocale(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getLocale());
                    LanguageLocale.getInstance().getContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getConfiguration(), LanguageLocale.getInstance().getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                }
                preference.setSummary(value);
                getActivity().finish();
                setPreferenceSummary(preference, value);

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
        return true;
    }

    private void setPreferenceSummary(Preference preference, String value) {
        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
            listPreference.setSummary(value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisplayPreferenceDialog(Preference preference) {
        try {
            if (preference.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("password_dialog")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ChangePassword.class));
            } else {
                super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        LanguageLocale.getInstance().getResources().updateConfiguration(LanguageLocale.getInstance().getConfiguration(), LanguageLocale.getInstance().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Log.e("OnPause:", "Preference Fragment");
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

*Below is product flavors and source set deifinition in build file*

```
productFlavors {
        Flavor1 {

        }
        Flavor2 {}

    }
    sourceSets {
        main{
            java {
                srcDirs('src/Flavor1/java/src', 'src/Flavor2/java/src','src/main/java/src')
            }
            res {
                srcDirs('src/Flavor1/res/src', 'src/Flavor2/res/src','src/main/res/src')
            }
        }
        Syriatel {
            java {
                srcDirs('src/Flavor1/java/src', 'src/main/java/src')
            }
            res {
                srcDirs('src/Flavor1/res/src', 'src/main/res/src')
            }
        }
        FMFI {
            java {
                srcDirs('src/Flavor2/java/src', 'src/main/java/src')
            }
            res {
                srcDirs('src/Flavor2/res/src', 'src/main/res/src')
            }
        }

    }
```

Can somebody please help me out i am unable to understand what i am doing wrong here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use this class to make it work:

```
object LocaleManager {

    val LANGUAGE_RUSSIAN = "ru"
    val LANGUAGE_UZBEK = "uz"
    val INITIALIZATED = "inited"
    private val LANGUAGE_KEY = "language_key"

    fun setLocale(c: Context): Context {
        return updateResources(c, getLanguage(c))
    }

    fun setNewLocale(c: Context, language: String): Context {
        initial(c)
        persistLanguage(c, language)
        return updateResources(c, language)
    }

    fun getLanguage(c: Context): String {
        val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c)
        return prefs.getString(LANGUAGE_KEY, LANGUAGE_RUSSIAN) ?: LANGUAGE_RUSSIAN
    }
    fun initial(c: Context){
        val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c)
        prefs.edit().putBoolean(INITIALIZATED,true).apply()
    }
    fun isInitialed(c: Context):Boolean{
        val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c)
        return prefs.getBoolean(INITIALIZATED,false)
    }
    fun restoreLang(c: Context){
        val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c)
        prefs.edit().putBoolean(INITIALIZATED,false).apply()
    }
    @SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")
    private fun persistLanguage(c: Context, language: String) {
        val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c)
        prefs.edit().putString(LANGUAGE_KEY, language).commit()
    }

    private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String): Context {
        var context = context
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val res = context.resources
        val config = Configuration(res.configuration)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            config.setLocale(locale)
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config)
        } else {
            config.locale = locale
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.displayMetrics)
        }
        return context
    }

    fun getLocale(res: Resources): Locale {
        val config = res.configuration
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) config.locales.get(0) else config.locale
    }
}
```

And then just add the next method in your BaseActivity class:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.setLocale(base))
}
```